# Change a Date-fields data before formated by model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model, lets call it Posts. 
Posts has a Date-field referring to a date other that created_on, updated_on e tc,
Lets call this field custom_date. 
When a user creates a post and inputs the custom_date field the POST will look like

```
params[:post][:custom_date] = "04/12/2013 01:01"
```

this is referring to day/month/year hour:minute.
When I call

```
@post= Post.new(post_params)
```

And then inspect @post the custom_date have been reformated to 2013-12-04 , without the hour and minute. I guess the format is the datebase (correct me if im wrong) way of storing the Date.

But, I want to get the hour and minute in here. So I figured that I could make this happen in a clean way in the model file:

```
private
    def fix_dates_from_input
        self.start_date = DateTime.parse(self.custom_date) unless start_date.custom_date?
        render text: self.inspect
    end
```

And call this before validation:

```
before_validation :fix_dates_from_input
```

How ever, it seems the date is formated when it gets to the model, so that I can't change it there (becouse I dont have the minute or hour data).

I was hoping that I could do this outside of the controller, 
Is there another way?

Comment: make sure the field type in db schema is date time rather than date.

Comment: That was it @xmpolaris ! Cant belive it was this simple! Thank you, merry christmas :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that your database is only storing the date and not the datetime.

Check the db/schema.rb file to see if this is the problem. If this is the issue, it will say something like:

```
create_table :posts do |t|
  ...
  t.date :custom_date
  ...
end
```

When it should look like this:

```
create_table :posts do |t|
  ...
  t.datetime :custom_date
  ...
end
```

To fix this you will either want to go back and fix the original migration (if it is a new project), or if you do not have the luxury of rebuilding your database from scratch, create a new migration to fix the problem:

From command line:

```
rails g migration change_custom_date_type
```

Then edit that file:

```
class ChangeCustomDateType < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :posts, :custom_date, :datetime
  end
end
```